# Where can I ask for a function with certain characteristics for statistical purposes?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

For statistical purposes, I am trying to construct a function that has a range of outputs given two inputs.

My math skills are not good enough to do it myself and I am certain there must be a single "correct way" of doing it. Where can I ask this question? On *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)*, or somewhere third Q&A site?

The question I want to ask is this:

---

> I want to construct a monotonic function that takes two inputs:
>
> - a number between 0 and 1 (input)
> - a factor
>
> the output should always be 0 when the input is 0, And 1 for input of 1
>
> The output is the input times the factor but limited by the "headroom" between the input and 1. So for numbers approaching zero it would be the input number times the factor (and 0 should output 0) and for input numbers approaching 1 the output should also approach 1.
>
> I have a solution that works for factors between 0 and 2:
>
> output = (factor-1)*(1-(input))+input
>
> it follows from the logic that only the headroom should be multiplied by the factor. But when the factor is above 2, the function is not monotonic anymore and the output goes above 1 for some input ranges

Answer (score 1):

You [posted your question on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4428418/228959), which is fine I guess. Unfortunately, it didn't draw that much attention (8 views in three months) - you could consider posting a bounty, but I'd recommend to [read this MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/228959) first and use that in your post. That's a legitimate reason to edit a post and you might get lucky and get an answer this time.

Here are similar questions which did get answered:

- [Looking for a function with some characteristics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1509583/228959)
- [Function with certain characteristics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2323039/228959)